# How do I make a cloth cape for LEGO?

Tags: rigging, cloth-simulation

I am trying to make a cloth cape for a LEGO Character, but the flow is always strange. It won't go down and won't stay still.
What am I doing wrong? [image]

Comment: show us what you tried so far. Best way: provide your blend file.

Answer (score 1):

ok, i made a "quick and dirty" example, how to do it.

Result: [image]

1. add a plane on ground -> passive, collision (gray)
2. add a rigid body (active) on it (green)
3. add a plane, which does NOT collide with other meshes when you place it
   3b) at lots of subdivision surface to plane, but not too much, else your computer explodes
4. add cloth modifier to plane, fix it with a vertex - pin group
5. raise qualitiy collisions to 20
6. add solidify modifier to plane with thickness -> apply
7. check object- and self collision
8. increase your outer thickness of your rigid body
9. let the other settings of cloth as they are -> little changes in the properties change a lot for the simulation

here is my blend file to check it out:
[image]